# WPF - Text box that grows vertically to accommodate all text

Tags: wpf, textbox, word-wrap, autogrow

The problem: I am not getting a textbox setting that will have a horizontally wordwrap and vertically auto grow functionality. I wish to do that by writing a code. I have written following code that creates a text box at mouse dblclick with wordwrap:

```
        TextBox text2 = new TextBox();
        text2.Width = 500;
        text2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        text2.Focus();
        text2.Height = 30;
        text2.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        text2.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        Point p = e.GetPosition(LayoutRoot);
        text2.Margin = new Thickness(p.X, p.Y, 0, 0);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(text2);
```

But, textbox does not grow vertically.
Can somebody suggest me a code in C# to do exactly what I desire?

Answer (score 5):

try using this

```
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

        TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Width = 100, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap };

        textBox.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(textBox);
        window.Content = grid;
```

where window is the Name assigned to Window(root).

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish the growth you're looking for is to use a string [measuring mechanism](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/2623.aspx) which you would run any time the text in your text box changes. Simply measure and resize your text box accordingly with any change to the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
text2.Height = double.NaN; // or don't set the property, but some custom styles might give a default value ..
text2.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
text2.MinHeight = 30; // or not if you want the styles default
```

instead of

```
text2.Height = 30;
```

not setting it or using double.NaN is the same as using 'Auto' in xaml.